# Maven Error in Eclipse - BPMN2 Modeler

Tags: eclipse, maven, jarsigner

my problem is the following. I have Eclipse Kepler SR1 and imported an maven project out of the following git: http://git.eclipse.org/c/bpmn2/.git/

This is a metamodel for the BPMN 2.0. After that i wanted to do a maven install but when i do this the following Error pops up

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.cbi.maven.plugins:eclipse-jarsigner-plugin:1.0.3:sign (sign) on project org.eclipse.bpmn2: Could not sign artifact org.eclipse.bpmn2:org.eclipse.bpmn2:eclipse-plugin:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Connection to http://build.eclipse.org:31338 refused: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the             following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.eclipse.bpmn2
```

Maven is correctly installed and i checked the superpom. There is no mistake in my opinion. I also updated the pluginRepository for plugin signin to https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/cbi-releases/. Is there anyone who knows the mistake and can help me?

Best Regards

Comment: What about this: ` Connection to http://build.eclipse.org:31338 refused: Connection timed out: connect -> `?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your error message contains a timeout for http://build.eclipse.org:31338 - that seems to me an internal address.

If I am not mistaken, this is used by the jar signer plug-in mentioned in the build script that is an eclipse.org-only service (for obvious reasons). Search for the followi

```
  <groupId>org.eclipse.cbi.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipse-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
```

As signing is an internal service, we in the EMF-IncQuery project execute signing only when a specific profile is selected, thus allowing building our project outside eclipse.org servers.